# Executing two tasks, which both update the plotly dashboard consecutively

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

We are trying to have an api-call that executes two tasks - a short and a long one. The short task should update the dashboard and when the long one is finished it should update the dashboard once again.

We tried to use:

- two callbacks, a normal and a long_callback, this leads to a forking error when used WSGI
- after_this_request
- Multiprocessing, does not work with WSGI

I think our attempts are the wrong approach, what is the right one?

Comment: Do you need to update the entire dashboard? Can you have each task update a limited section or specific components?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "api-call"? Are you trying to call an api end point to invoke callbacks, or something else? And what does "update the dashboard" mean? Is it some underlying data that changes? Or do you want to refresh the page for connected users? Or something different?